How to modify request parameters in Ktor Custom Plugin?
I have created a custom plugin which needs to set and remove query parameters from the request.
val UniqueUserPlugin = createRouteScopedPlugin(name = "UniqueUserPlugin", createConfiguration = ::UniqueUserPluginConfiguration) {

    onCall { call ->
        val request = call.request
        request.rawQueryParameters.append("param", "123") //todo how to edit requests parameters

    }


}



There is no append on the parameters field on the request.
Is there a way to do this with this custom plugin API or even in the custom plugin base api using interceptors etc?

Can you tell me why you want to remove the query parameters from the request?
